# Dual Booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu, how I can SSH to both of them flawlessly?

Tags: networking, dual-boot, server, permissions, ssh

I'm dual booting Windows and Ubuntu, and I am using a program that sends commands via SSH for Ubuntu. I decided to apply the same when I am on Windows but the problem is obviously, they both have the same IP (ssh user@IP) and with that I am receiving MITM Attack warning and can't get through.

I tried using ssh user@hostname but after entering the password I get, Permission Denied.

Show me some workaround please?

Answer (score 2):

Try running ssh server on different ports, maybe that will help.

Say Linux on port 22 and Windows on port 222.

Another idea is to copy the same ssh fingerprint/ public key across Linux and Windows.

Comment: _“copy the same ssh fingerprint/ public key”_ Especially the _private_ key would be needed.